# Separate dataset by columns as a certain character appears

Tags: r, dataset

How can I separate a dataset in columns as ',' appears? Like, the example below:

```
ACTIVITY,TIME,SL,EEG,BP,HR,CIRCLUATION
3,4722.92,4019.64,-1.60E+03,13,79,317
2,4059.12,2191.03,-1146.08,20,54,165
```

The dataset is separated only by ',' and not (also) by columns.
I want to make it like this:

```
ACTIVITY, TIME,      SL,       EEG,        BP,     HR,       CIRCLUATION
    3,     4722.92, 4019.64,  -1.60E+03,  13,      79,          317
    2,     4059.12, 2191.03,  -1146.08,   20,      54,          165
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `read.csv` ? This looks to just be a comma-separated values text file, unless there is a complexity I'm missing.

Comment: Actually it is! I was thinking it wrong! Never mind and thanks for the answer / help!